# regex expression any character with spaces and carriage returns

Tags: regex, carriage-return

I would like to find an regex expression that contains any characters and any carriage returns:

Example . I would like to find the String from "Mytext.." to "EndofMyText"

```
Anytext
Mytextstartshere
        more text
        more text
EndofMyText
LastTet
```

my Problem is the carriage returns.
What is the correct regex match expression ? :

I started with : `Mytext(.*?[\r\n])EndofMyText`

Comment: We need to know in which language you are programming.

Comment: Do you need to get a specific text for the `Mytextstartshere` ? if not try `[^\t\n]+(\n\t[^\t\n]+)+\n[^\t\n]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could repeat this part one or more times `(?:.*?[\r\n])+` and make it a non capturing group

[`Mytext(?:.*?[\r\n])+EndofMyText`](https://regex101.com/r/5H8rhp/1)

or use `[\s\S]+?`

[`Mytext[\s\S]+?EndofMyText`](https://regex101.com/r/WPvX73/1)

When using a flag for dot matches newline, you could use [`Mytext.*?EndofMyText`](https://regex101.com/r/5H8rhp/4)